# How to remove top node from linked list and put it on the top of another linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

So basically when

```
void moveFirstNode(MusicPlayer fromList, MusicPlayer toList)
```

is called it should move the first node from `fromList` to the top of  `toList`. If empty, it does nothing.

How would I go about doing that? Any tips/ hints. Also its gotta have O(1) worst case. Havent tried anything yet, just looking for ideas, especially for the worst-cast 0(1) part. Sorry if thats not permitted.

Thanks

Comment: remove(), add()?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Java's in-built LinkedList class:

```
void moveFirstNode(LinkedList<MusicPlayer> fromList, LinkedList<MusicPlayer> toList) {
    if((fromList != null) && (toList != null) && (fromList.size() > 0)) {
        toList.addFirst(fromList.pollFirst());
    }
}
```